# django-mptt error with existing model

Tags: django, django-admin, django-mptt

I already have model topic and have data in it, when I tried to use MPTTMODEL insted of the regular model

```
class Topic(MPTTModel):
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')
    ....
```

so I run the following command to migrate the parent column in the topic table

```
./manage.py evolve --hint --execute
```

but I get this error

```
Error: Cannot use hinted evolution: AddField or ChangeField mutation for 'Topic.rght' in 'core' requires user-specified initial value.
```

it works fine with new model, but with existing Model that has data it raise this error

Comment: I know it's not much help but I had this issue before and you basically need to generate the tree based on the existing foreignkey link that should exist on the table.